# How to get n elements of a list not contained in another one?

Tags: python

I have two lists, of different size (either one can be larger than the other one), with some common elements. I would like to get  `n` elements from the first list which are not in the second one.

I see two families of solutions (the example below is for `n=3`)

```
a = [i for i in range(2, 10)]
b = [i * 2 for i in range (1, 10)]
# [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]

# solution 1: generate the whole list, then slice
s1 = list(set(a) - set(b))
s2 = [i for i in a if i not in b]

for i in [s1, s2]:
    print (i[:3])

# solution 2: the simple loop solution
c = 0
s3 = []
for i in a:
    if i not in b:
        s3.append(i)
        c += 1
        if c == 3:
            break
print(s3)
```

All of the them are correct, the output is

```
[9, 3, 5]
[3, 5, 7]
[3, 5, 7]
```

(the first solution does not give the *first* 3 ones because `set` does not preserve the order - but this is OK in my case as I will have unsorted (even explicitly shuffled) lists anyway)

Are there the most pythonic and reasonably optimal ones?

The solution 1 first computes the difference, then slices - which I find quite inefficient (the sizes of my lists will be ~100k elements, I will be looking for the first 100 ones).

The solution 2 looks more optimal but it is ugly (which is a matter of taste, but I learned that when something looks ugly in Python, it means that there are usually more pythonic solution).

I will settle for solution 2 if there are no better alternatives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use set.difference and slice:

```
print(list(set(a).difference(b))[:3])
[3, 5, 7]
```

set.difference already gives you elements in a that are not in b:

```
set([3, 5, 7, 9])
```

So you just need a slice of that.

Or without calling list in the set use iter, next and a comprehension:

```
diff = iter(set(a).difference(b))
n = 3
sli = [next(diff) for _ in range(n)]
print(sli)
```

.difference does not create a second set so it is a more efficient solution:

```
In [1]: a = [i for i in range(2, 10000000)]  
In [2]: b = [i * 2 for i in range (1, 10000000)]   
In [3]: timeit set(a).difference(b)
1 loops, best of 3: 848 ms per loop    
In [4]: timeit set(a)- set(b)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.54 s per loop
```

For the large lists above `s2 = [i for i in a if i not in b]` would give you enough time to cook a meal before it finished.

Using iter and .difference:

```
In [11]: %%timeit                                
diff = iter(set(a).difference(b))
n = 3
sli = [next(diff) for _ in range(n)]
   ....: 
1 loops, best of 3: 797 ms per loop
```

Comment: is it better than my `list(set(a) - set(b))`? (from an efficiency perspective, particularly for large lists)

Comment: @WoJ, yes it is more efficient, I added some timings

Answer (score 2):

It might be marginally faster to avoid constructing the full difference if you only need 100, but by how much is going to depend on your dataset.

```
import random
from itertools import islice

def m1(a,b):
    return list(set(a) - set(b))[:100]
def m2(a,b):
    return list(set(a).difference(b))[:100] 
def m3(a,b):
    return list(islice(set(a).difference(b), 100))
def m4(a,b):
    bset = set(b)
    return list(islice((x for x in a if x not in bset), 100))
```

gives me

```
>>> a = [random.randint(0, 10**6) for i in range(10**5)]
>>> b = [random.randint(0, 10**6) for i in range(10**5)]
>>> %timeit m1(a,b)
10 loops, best of 3: 121 ms per loop
>>> %timeit m2(a,b)
10 loops, best of 3: 98.7 ms per loop
>>> %timeit m3(a,b)
10 loops, best of 3: 82.3 ms per loop
>>> %timeit m4(a,b)
10 loops, best of 3: 42.8 ms per loop
>>> 
>>> a = list(range(10**5))
>>> b = [i*2 for i in a]
>>> %timeit m1(a,b)
10 loops, best of 3: 58.7 ms per loop
>>> %timeit m2(a,b)
10 loops, best of 3: 50.8 ms per loop
>>> %timeit m3(a,b)
10 loops, best of 3: 40.7 ms per loop
>>> %timeit m4(a,b)
10 loops, best of 3: 21.7 ms per loop
```

With a little more work you could even avoiding needing to make the full `bset`.  If you're very likely to find 100 missing if you only look at the first 10^4 or so of the list, for example, it might be worth trying that first.  But I'd be surprised if this turned out to be a bottleneck in your code, and so it's probably not worth worrying about.

Comment: How does iter and the list comp stack up?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: looks to be pretty comparable to the list-islice combination.

Answer (score 0):

Could turn b into a set but not a. Set up a generator to exploit laziness, then use a comprehension to get the items you want:

```
a = [i for i in range(2, 10)]
b = [i * 2 for i in range (1, 10)]
bset = set(b)
agen = (i for i in a if not i in set(b))
first3 = [j for (i,j) in enumerate(agen) if i < 3]
print(first3)
```